# Can a woman feature in EPL?

Tags: rules, football, english-premier-league, gender

I know this may be a silly question but I couldn't help asking out of curiosity. We know that there is a separate league for women's football in England, but say if there is a female who is really good player and can play alongside men in EPL, can she do that, or is there a rule that will prohibit her from playing?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, unfortunately there IS an explicit rule against mixed gender teams so no, a promoted side couldn't sign any top female players

This absurd rule was tested in 2004 when Celaya, a Mexican Second Division team attempted to sign Maribel Dominguez a star of the Mexican Women's team. But FIFA blocked it Woman barred from men's football

In England, the FA has recently voted to extend the age at which "mixed gender football" is permitted, from 16 to 18 years FA to raise girls' football age limit

According to this Netherlands and Switzerland allow mixed gender football until 19, Germany and Italy at 17. Bear in mind this doesn't just apply to professional football, but to any organised matches at all under a league structure. So girls and guys can no doubt have a kick about in the park, but can't play together in any organised league at any level.

Comment: Sources, please.

Comment: Line J3 in the FA handbook seems to be the best source I can find: http://www.thefa.com/-/media/files/thefaportal/governance-docs/rules-of-the-association/2017-18-final/014_rules-of-the-association.ashx

Comment: @origimbo, can you please tell what line J3 tells? What page is it on? Searching "J3" in the document didn't return any results.

Comment: @gdrt the 38th page of that pdf (labelled as 132), section J, paragraph 3, "Players in a Match must be of the same gender save for matches in a playing season in the age groups Under 7 to Under 18 inclusive (as defined at Rule C)."

Answer (score 0):

The whole team has to be an U18 team for mixed gender, so a 17yo girl can't play for a EPL/EFL team, or even in adult amateur leagues which are governed by the FA (which is probably all leagues in English football - maybe some 5 a-side astro turf amateur leagues allow it, but definitely no FA-controlled leagues): "Players in a Match must be of the same gender save for matches in a playing season in the age groups Under 7 to Under 18 inclusive (as defined at Rule C)."

Comment: welcome to Sports SE. Please add an explicit reference to the source, even though it's prob the one already linked on another answer on this page.